# spring-boot integration testing using rest-assured

Tags: maven, spring-boot, h2

I have been struggling with the issue of starting the H2 db in my tests. This is how the tests are annotated -

```
  @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ServiceApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest("server.port:8084")
@PropertySource("test:application.properties")
public class testSerivce{
//test scenario
}
```

The in memory db H2 is used and this is how its setup in application property file -

```
dataSource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
dataSource.url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:59000/./target/service-db;MODE=Oracle;IGNORECASE=TRUE;IFEXISTS=TRUE
dataSource.username=sa
dataSource.password=sa
dataSource.maxActive=2
dataSource.initialSize=1
dataSource.maxIdle=1
```

When I right click and run the tests the H2 db is not getting setup with the service and the tests are not able to connect with database and failing.

Whereas when I run the tests using the maven profile,as thy are running in teamcity everything works and the tests work but it runs all the 10tests .

What should I do? I am stuck at this issue for many days. Which annotation should I use or how to setup the H2 setup so that they also run with the service.

Comment: What's the error when you run the tests with the service? Also try changing the ```@PropertySource("test:application.properties")``` -> ```@PropertySource("application.properties")```

Comment: @NitinArora now getting error this error

Comment: ERROR 7384 --- [nio-8084-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/paymentservice] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'application.empty' for locale 'en_US'.] with root cause

org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'application.empty' for locale 'en_US'.
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:186)

Comment: You are using locale specific messages and there is no file for en_US messages. Create a file ```messages_en.properties``` file at this location ```/src/main/resources/messages_en.properties```

Comment: that is written in product code and I am having issues in my tests. As a good practice I should not inject any code in dev side but make my tests work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Eclipse? 
I somehow noticed that src/main/resources/application.properties gets excluded from the Java Build Path,  if you generate the project with the "eclipse:eclipse" maven goal.

To workaround this you can either add a src/test/resources/application.properties or correct the Java Build Path.

I don't know if this behavior is intended. I guess it is because of the resource exclusions/inclusions in spring-boot-starter-parent

Comment: I am using intellij not eclipse. the error is seen when I start the service thru my tests...can it be linked to the annotation @EnableWebMvc used in the appcontextConfig file for initailizing the beans with the resourse and useing that bean?

Comment: @joshiste..your answer helped me in a big way..thanks a ton :)